# JSON and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this thing working mostly.  What I don't get is, if I have the file on my desktop and drag it into a browser, it works.  If I upload the same file to my website and visit it, it displays nothing in Firefox.  Last night it worked in Safari, but today it does not.  Is something really weird in this code?
Here is the [pastie](http://pastie.textmate.org/private/q9plfcbp1madj1e1bnkng) in case pasting all this in here does not work :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body{
        background: #353535;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 62.5%;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    p{
        font-size: 1.6em;
        font-family: Arial, "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
    }
    span{
        font-size: 1.6em;
        font-variant: small-caps;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    li {
        font-size: 1.6em;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    img{
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>

<!-- actual api http://api.tinychat.com/designtalk.json -->
<!-- testing file  test.json -->

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.tinychat.com/designtalk.json",
        function(data){

        $('#name').append(data.name);
        $('#topic').append(data.topic);
        $('#broadcast').append(data.broadcaster_count);
        $('#count').append(data.total_count);
        $('#priv').append(data.priv);

if(!data.name)
{
    alert("Room empty!")
}

    var $nameList = $('<ul></ul>');

    $.each(data.names, function (i, val) {
      $('<li></li>').appendTo($nameList).html(val); 
    });

    $('#container').append($nameList);

    $.each(data.pics, function (i, val) {

        $("<img/>").attr("src", val).appendTo("#images");

    });

        });

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="name"><span>Room Name:</span> </p>
    <p id="topic"><span>Current Topic:</span> </p>
    <p id="broadcast"><span>Number Broadcasting:</span> </p>
    <p id="count"><span>Total in Room:</span> </p>
    <p id="priv"><span>Number with Privileges:</span> </p>

    <div id="container"><span>Who is Online?</span></div>
    <div id="images"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create HTML elements programmatically, to build an HTML List for example:

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo('#container').html(data.title);

var $nameList = $('<ul></ul>');

$.each(data.names, function (i, val) {
  $('<li></li>').appendTo($nameList).html(val);
});

$('#container').append($nameList);
```

Example [here](http://jsbin.com/uweto).

Without jQuery:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container'),
    title = document.createElement('div'),
    nameList = document.createElement('ul'), li;

title.innerHTML = data.title;
for (var i = 0; i < data.names.length; i++) {
  li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = data.names[i];
  nameList.appendChild(li);
}

container.appendChild(title);
container.appendChild(nameList);
```

Example [here](http://jsbin.com/ikupu).

**Edit:** In response to your comment, you were missing the [Flickr specific](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html) parameter `jsoncallback` to make the JSONP request, and also in the structure of the JSON response the `names` member doesn't exists, I think you mean `items`.

Check your feed example fixed [here](http://jsbin.com/oqize).

Comment: +1, I love that you've got two examples, one in pure JS and one in jQuery, and they've both been tested :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I am still stuck though and do not know why.  I tried this jquery method with a test JSON feed from flickr, but nothing is happening.  Am I missing something stupid?  Here is the code, was not enough room here, so it's on pastie.  http://pastie.textmate.org/private/wqtv1pgtri0fpnrkczgifw 
Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again guys, I changed my original post to reflect what the current problem is, I hope you can help thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the callback function you would just go through each element.  Let's say you wanted to append the names to a div with the id of namesDiv you might do this:

```
$.get("something.aspx", function(json) {  
  for(var i =0; i< json.names.length; i++)
    {
      $('#namesDiv').append(json.names[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a firefox plugin which formats json data. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10869

This is assuming you only want to learn what the json data looks like and hence start programming in it...

Answer (score 0):

Very long in the tooth, but it does take care to recognize that properties of your object may have their own properties as well.  Assumes a DIV element (or similar) exists with an ID of "content."

```
function WriteObject(obj, tabs)
{
  tabs = tabs || 0;

  var padding = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < tabs; ++i)
  {
    padding += "\&nbsp;";   
  }

  for(var prop in obj)
  { 
    if(typeof(obj[prop]) === "object")
    {
      if(obj[prop].constructor === Array)
      {
        var str = obj[prop].join(",");
        $("#content").append(padding + prop + ": " + str + "<br />");           
      }     
      else
      {
        $("#content").append(padding + prop + "<br />");
        WriteObject(obj[prop], tabs + 1);   
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $("#content").append(padding + prop + ": " + (obj[prop] ? obj[prop] : "null") + "<br />");            
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the page below:
In modern browsers you don't need anymore the json2.js library from [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <pre id="res"></pre>

    <script>
        var json = {
          "title":"No title", 
          "names":["", "dave", "jeff", "sean", "", ""],
          "total_people":3 
        };
        document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```